# Formulas for Barrel/Pincushion distortion

Tags: image-processing, distortion

Can't understand how to get (x', y') of original (x, y) in image, for  Barrel/Pincushion distortion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Section 2 of [**this paper**](http://sprg.massey.ac.nz/pdfs/2003_IVCNZ_408.pdf) explains the transformation. Basically:

[image]

Here I made an example in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/):

[image]

Comment: When recreating this code in openGL without trimming (like you have in the 1st 2 pictures) the image looked disjointed. I had more success using this algorithm http://www.geeks3d.com/20140213/glsl-shader-library-fish-eye-and-dome-and-barrel-distortion-post-processing-filters/2/

Comment: Your transform is only valid for turning a rectilinear image into a distorted image, to reverse that distortion you need the inverse function which is `p1 = cbrt(2 / (3 * a));
 p2 = cbrt( sqrt(3*a) * sqrt( 27*a*x*x + 4 ) - 9*a*x );
 p3 = cbrt(2) * pow(3*a, 2/3);

 return p1/p2 - p2/p3;`

Answer (score 3):

simple barrel\pincushion distortion in opencv c++

```
IplImage* barrel_pincusion_dist(IplImage* img, double Cx,double Cy,double kx,double ky)
{
    IplImage* mapx = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
    IplImage* mapy = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );

    int w= img->width;
    int h= img->height;

    float* pbuf = (float*)mapx->imageData;
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {         
            float u= Cx+(x-Cx)*(1+kx*((x-Cx)*(x-Cx)+(y-Cy)*(y-Cy)));
            *pbuf = u;
            ++pbuf;
        }
    }

    pbuf = (float*)mapy->imageData;
    for (int y = 0;y < h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) 
        {
            *pbuf = Cy+(y-Cy)*(1+ky*((x-Cx)*(x-Cx)+(y-Cy)*(y-Cy)));
            ++pbuf;
        }
    }

    /*float* pbuf = (float*)mapx->imageData;
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        int ty= y-Cy;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            int tx= x-Cx;
            int rt= tx*tx+ty*ty;

            *pbuf = (float)(tx*(1+kx*rt)+Cx);
            ++pbuf;
        }
    }

    pbuf = (float*)mapy->imageData;
    for (int y = 0;y < h; y++)
    {
        int ty= y-Cy;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) 
        {
            int tx= x-Cx;
            int rt= tx*tx+ty*ty;

            *pbuf = (float)(ty*(1+ky*rt)+Cy);
            ++pbuf;
        }
    }*/

    IplImage* temp = cvCloneImage(img);
    cvRemap( temp, img, mapx, mapy ); 
    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    cvReleaseImage(&mapx);
    cvReleaseImage(&mapy);

    return img;
}
```

more complicated form
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Answer (score 2):

An approximation of the polynomial radial distortion model you can find in `Fitzgibbon, 2001` is

[image]

where rd and ru are the distances from the center of distortion. This is also used to filter the distortion out of a wide-angle camera image for computer vision and image processing purposes.

You can find a more detailed explanation of the principle and the shader code to implement the undistortion filtering (and also the forward transformation) here: http://marcodiiga.github.io/radial-lens-undistortion-filtering

I'm also posting the papers you should take a look at if you want to know the mathematical details for the method I posted

- Zhang Z. (1999). Flexible camera calibration by viewing a plane from unknown orientation
- Andrew W. Fitzgibbon (2001). Simultaneous linear estimation of multiple view geometry and lens distortion

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, there can also be an r to the power 4 term too. The signs of the two constants (for the r to the 2 and r to the 4 terms) can be opposite giving handlebar distortion where the centre of the image has barrel distortion and the edge has pincushion distortion giving straight lines the appearance of a handlebar moustache.