# Mapping a 2D grid onto a sphere

Tags: language-agnostic, trigonometry

I want to map a grid to a sphere like this:

[image: grid to sphere mapping]

In other words, for every point `(x, y)` ∈[0,1] on the left, I need the `(x, y, z)` coordinates of the equivalent point on the sphere, between the -45º and +45º meridians on each axis. You can also think of the source coordinates as two angles such that:

```
phi   = -45º + x * 90º
theta = -45º + y * 90º
```

The traditional latitude-longitude or polar formulas I've found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/969880/538711) are of no use because [the results they produce are only distorted along one axis](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1735705/crxcry.jpg). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate barrel distortion? If so, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199636/formulas-for-barrel-pincushion-distortion

Comment: If I understand it correctly, barrel distortion is a purely two-dimensional effect? If so, I'm afraid it's not what I need. This is more like cube mapping. I'm generating procedural planets textured with cubemaps (think Spore) so I need it to be 3D.

Comment: This reminds me a lot a conformal mapping... Have you tried it already?

Answer (score 1):

Define two functions, `a` and `b`, that map your x and y coordinates to the appropriate theta and phi angles:

```
a(x) = (pi / 4) * (2x - 1)
b(y) = (pi / 4) * (4y + 1)
```

And then just [map the resulting spherical coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Cartesian_coordinates) back into a Cartesian coordinate:

[image]

You'll get a function of r, x', y', members of [0, 1] x [0, 1], which will map the 2D coordinate onto a sphere of radius r.

Comment: Thanks for the `a(x)` and `b(x)` mapping functions, they saved me some work. Unfortunately, the formulas for spherical coordinate mapping don't get me the results I need. I tried them out on Excel anyway and got this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1735705/grid2sphere_blender_excel.jpg which confirmed my suspicions. It has to be some form of cube mapping, not ECP (latitude-longitude) mapping.